# Display TinyMCE content in datagridview c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, tinymce

i tried add TinyMCE to my textbox using multiLine property in **AddMemo.aspx** page and it was successfull. Here is my javascript sintax in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager,filemanager",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false,
        template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js"
    });
</script>
```

Here us the picture:

[image]

when click on Submit button, it will be saved to database. I don't know how to display TiniMCE content sintax to my DataGridview (i use binding source) in **HistoryMemo.aspx**.
Here the result:
[image]

Anyone can help me to display TiniMCE content from database to my **datagridview** i will appreciate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna show TinyMCE content from database to your datagridview just add this code to your datagriview page to decode html in all column of your datagridview:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    string encoded = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Text = Context.Server.HtmlDecode(encoded);
                }
            }
        }
```

if you wanna decode to spesific column (ex. first) column add this code:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
  e.Row.Cells[0].Text = decodedText;
}
```

you can customize based on your needed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `@Html.Raw` to stop .NET from escaping your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**SqlDataReader help you to display content without html tags**

```
string strQuery = "SELECT * from table";
using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(con))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, myCon))
    {
        myCon.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = sdr;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            sdr.Close();
        }
        myCon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: **Welcome to StackOverFlow, @SajithKumar !** While this does answer the question, a bit of explanation for the code would be beneficial to us all.